# How can I calculate inflation rate and unemployment rate from this data set in R

Tags: r, analysis

Here is the head of my dataset.

```
 Year Months   CPI  UEL   CLF
1 1948      1 23.68 2034 60230
2 1948      2 23.67 2328    NA
3 1948      3 23.50 2399    NA
4 1948      4 23.82 2386 60535
5 1948      5 24.01 2118    NA
6 1948      6 24.15 2214    NA
```

CPI stands for "Consumer Price Index", UEL is the "Unemployment Level", and CLF is the "Civilian Labor Force". The data is between the years 1948 and 2016. I was only given the Civilian Labor Force figures for months 1, 4, 7, and 10 of each year. I need to calculate the variables Inflation Rate and Unemployment Rate from these variables but I'm not sure how to do that in RStudio.

Comment: How do you calculate `CLF` values? Is there some formula? What would be final values for the data that you have shared?

Comment: I did not calculate CLF, I was given the variable as part of the original dataset. I was tasked with creating the other two variables just from what variables I'm given.

Comment: @GattMola, it will be better if you could give sample expected output for the given six rows of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your problem seems with `ECONOMICS` rather than programming in `r`.  You have to first decide about strategies to calculate `NA`s in data (`CLF`) which can be

- same as previous
- increasing/decreasing proportionately

Thereafter you can calculate `unemployment rate` in r.

For calculation of inflation you can use lag/lead from `dplyr`.

Something like this will work, if you want to fill blanks with previous values only.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% fill(CLF, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(inflation = paste0(formatC((CPI - lag(CPI))*100/lag(CPI), digits = 2), "%"),
         unemployment_rate = paste0(formatC(UEL*100/CLF, digits = 2), "%"))

  Year Months   CPI  UEL   CLF inflation unemployment_rate
1 1948      1 23.68 2034 60230       NA%              3.4%
2 1948      2 23.67 2328 60230   -0.042%              3.9%
3 1948      3 23.50 2399 60230    -0.72%                4%
4 1948      4 23.82 2386 60535      1.4%              3.9%
5 1948      5 24.01 2118 60535      0.8%              3.5%
6 1948      6 24.15 2214 60535     0.58%              3.7%
```

If you want results without formatting as `percentages`

```
df %>% fill(CLF, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(inflation = (CPI - lag(CPI))*100/lag(CPI),
         unemployment_rate = UEL*100/CLF)

  Year Months   CPI  UEL   CLF   inflation unemployment_rate
1 1948      1 23.68 2034 60230          NA          3.377055
2 1948      2 23.67 2328 60230 -0.04222973          3.865183
3 1948      3 23.50 2399 60230 -0.71820870          3.983065
4 1948      4 23.82 2386 60535  1.36170213          3.941521
5 1948      5 24.01 2118 60535  0.79764903          3.498802
6 1948      6 24.15 2214 60535  0.58309038          3.657388
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Anil. I wasn't completely sure the best way to deal with the empty months and your method seems more manageable than leaving them be.

Comment: If you have the time, could you explain what the 'paste0' and 'formatC' arguments are?

Comment: `paste0` and `formatC` both are purely optional, I have used these to format output rates as `percentages` and nothing else.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. For some reason, when I use the code, I'm getting back only "0%" for each cell in "inflation". Here's the head:

Comment: 'Year Months   CPI  UEL   CLF inflation unemployment_rate
1 1948      1 23.68 2034 60230        0%              3.4%'

Comment: maybe that's not 0 but nearly 0 and shown as 0 in your console

Comment: A minor correction in the answer, pls note